# Insert Binary Seed Data From Database Project File

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

We currently have a bunch of seed scripts which run when we publish our database projects and look something like;

```
INSERT INTO cpp_document_type 
(
    document_type_id,
    document_type_name
)
VALUES
( 1, N'Safe Contractor Certificate (PDF/DOC)' ), 
( 2, N'Health and Risk Assessment (PDF/DOC)' )
```

Great. But in some scenarios we want to insert binary data. We are aware that we can do;

```
INSERT INTO cpp_documents
(
    document_data
)
VALUES
( SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'\\path\file.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) ), 
( SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'\\path\file2.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) )
```

But that relies on the files being in an absolute location and the SQL server being able to access that location.

I would like to include the files in the database project, then do something more like;

```
:setvar BinaryFile "Files\file.jpg"
:setvar BinaryFile2 "Files\file2.jpg"

INSERT INTO cpp_documents
(
    document_data
)
VALUES
( $(BinaryFile) ), 
( $(BinaryFile2) )
```

Thanks

Comment: Either you supply the path to the file contents and it's accessible from the server or you write down as a literal binary (the one that it's representation starts with `0x`) the contents of the file, which can make your script huge. Other method is to transfer the contents with an ETL tool like SSIS or using linkedservers.